# How to count vertices (or edges) using `anytree`?

Tags: python, anytree

I would like to determine the size of a tree by *number of vertices*.

Clearly,

```py
len(list(PreOrderIter(root)))
```

gives me this number.

Is this the way to do it?

In other words, is there a recommended dedicated function or something for this in `anytree`?

Can the above be possibly more efficient somehow?

Comment: `num_of_edges = num_of_vertices - 1` in a tree, so the two are essentially the same.

Comment: In any case `sum(1 for _ in iter)` is more memory-efficient than `len(list(iter))`. I don't know if it's faster.